# what is matplotlib's retina display mode?

Tags: python, matplotlib

What is retina display mode in matplotlib? I searched a lot and only thing I get is how to use it in jupyter notebook. How is it different? Does it have something to do with apple's retina display?

EDIT:

In jupyter notebook, this is how the code is written:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'
```

My doubt is what does this retina mode does? How is it different from other modes?

Comment: Perhaps read [this](https://gist.github.com/minrk/3301035)

Comment: thanks, i was reading this. But, i am confused when it was mentioned that 2x was ugly. I tried to look at the difference, but, i don't seem to find it much different.

Comment: What exactly are you refering to when saying "retina display in matplotlib"? Is this any setting? Where does it occur?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just that the definition of the displayed plot is a bit better: retina quality. Any display with retina resolution will make the figures look better - if your monitor's resolution is sub-retina than the improvement will be less noticeable.